# Pandas read_csv error out for url despite url is valid

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a problem with read_csv with url, the code below run into errors despite the url is valid.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 102, in read_csv
    f = com._get_handle(filepath_or_buffer, 'r', encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/common.py", line 633, in _get_handle
    f = open(path, mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv'
>>>
```

read_csv only runs if the file exist in my directory

```
df = pd.read_csv("./none_list.csv")
```

This is kind of confusing since the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) says that the string could be an url.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: It is working for me, can you try restarting your terminal?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Works fine for me using pandas 0.16.2, python 3.4 64-bit Windows 7, BT Broadband, England.....

Comment: I am using pandas `'0.7.0'` in Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS , I also tried restarting the terminal

Comment: Problem fixed after updating pandas to 0.16.2 , although its kind of weird that pip doesn't default to the latest stable release

Comment: pip defaults to the latest stable. However, if you do not setup virtualenvs, and then for instance you clone some app and run `pip install -r somerequirements.txt` this will uninstall your latest stable and install the version specified in the requirements file.